# Heading order in HTML5

Tags: html, seo, semantic-markup

This is a webpage example of my site:

```
<html>

<title> artilce header </title>

<body>
    <header> <h1> nme of website</h1></header>

    <section>
        <h2> name of section</h2>

        <article>
            <h3>article header</h3>

        </article>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to know if this order is correct? Or does it maybe have a bad effect on SEO?

header is in all pages, section must have an header because of header/…

For example, do I I have to change it to something like this:

```
<html>

<title> artilce header </title>

<body>
    <header> <h2> nme of website</h2></header>

    <section>
        <h3> name of section</h3>

        <article>
            <h1>article header</h1>

        </article>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both variants are valid HTML5.

The HTML5 spec says about [headings and sections](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/sections.html#headings-and-sections):

> Sections may contain headings of any rank, and authors are strongly encouraged to use headings of the appropriate rank for the section's nesting level.

So your first example is recommended by HTML5.

HTML5 [does not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21641084/1591669) define that `h1` would be more "important" than `h6`.
How consumers (like search engines) interpret this is up to them and it most likely differs from consumer to consumer, so you’d have to check their documentation.

Comment: To be clear, h1 is a higher rank than h6. Which may be a different meaning than "important" but I wouldn't think so.

Answer (score -1):

Use your Second Concept it looks simple and good as per SEO.