# Which tag to use for site title and headings for other secondary sections

Tags: html, seo, semantic-markup, html-heading

With **SEO**, **semantics**, and **document outlines** in mind, which tags are right (or the most commonly used) for site title and headings for other secondary sections (e.g. sidebar, related links)?

Example document:

```html
<header>
  <h1>I'm Site Name, not the title of actual article</h1>
</header>

<aside>
  <h1>And I'm sidebar heading, ain't about the article of this page either</h1>
</aside>

<article>
  <h1>I'm the title of article, supposed to be what this page is all about</h1>

  <p>intro...<p>

  <h2>Subhead. Make site name and section heading a h2 tag, and I'm equal to them.</h2>
  <p>text of about the subhead...</p>
</article>
```

These are 3 guidelines that I have thought of:

Guideline 1: **the way nobody does**

- `strong` tags on both site title and section headings.

Guideline 2: **site title = article's subtopics**

- `h2` tag on site title; and
- `h3` tags on section headings

Guideline 3: **just use one kind of heading tag**

- Any heading tag (most likely h2, h3 or h4) for both site title and section headings.

Comment: Can you include a minimal example that shows the structure of the document?

Comment: @unor, I've added a minimal example.

Answer (score 0):

Either you use `h1` for each section (like in your example snippet), or you use the heading elements of the appropriate rank (corresponding to nesting levels of your sections).

Both ways have their [pros and cons](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/274668/63183), but the HTML5 spec encourages authors to use the latter way ([probably because of old or non-conforming user agents](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35349232/1591669)).

Following that advice, your snippet would be:

```html
<header>
  <h1>Site name</h1>
</header>

<aside>
  <h2>Aside title</h2>
</aside>

<article>
  <h2>Article title</h2>

  <section>
    <h3>Subhead</h3>
  </section>

</article>
```

Note that I added a `section` element for the implicit section started by the "Subhead" heading. This is [encouraged by HTML5, too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24987792/1591669).

Comment: Thank you, would upvote if I could. The only question is, wouldn't it hurt if we give the higher heading tag to the site title than to the article title, even when the page mainly about the article itself?

Comment: I also think that aside's heading should be lower to site title and the article.

Comment: Or maybe it's actually subjective and I'm overthinking its small effect in SEO and document outlines?

Comment: @ChristopherDelaPaz: The rank of HTML headings [does not represent](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30620192/1591669) "importance". Something under `h2` is not necessarily more important or relevant than something under `h3`. Consumers (like search engines) may of course try to interpret it in some way like that, but this would be specific to this consumer (and it would certainly break with many documents that use headings for their purpose, i.e., giving structure / an outline, instead of a possible SEO effect).

Comment: @ChristopherDelaPaz: That said, asking for SEO advice (what is good/bad for SEO) is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Such questions are on-topic on [webmasters.se], e.g., see: [<h1> - Semantic impact vs. SEO impact](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/83012/17633).

Answer (score 0):

After more research (and sort of validation), I've come with a solution that appropriately (I hope) implies the hierarchy of importance to SEO.

**For article page**

- use h1 tag for article title
- use h2 to h3 for sub topics
- use h2 for site title
- use h3 for aside titles

**for home page**

- use h1 tag for site title

---

**edit**
I agree with explicit usage of section on each subtopic as @unor's [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36169397/6091765).

Comment: Could you share some links from your research? Where is it suggested that the site title should be an h2 on article pages?

Answer (score -1):

You are doing it correct, but you should have only one  tag on each page and include your most important keywords in it.

Comment: "...only one tag on each page..." — do you mean the h1 tag?